# How to manage ambari server using Puppet?

Tags: puppet, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I want to manage `ambari` server using different tools like `Ansible`, `Puppet`, `salt` and similar. Using `Ansible` I did it, but with `Puppet` I have a problem:

I want to interact with the `ambari` API to start some services(`hive`, `hdfs`, `smartsense` etc), but in the philosophy of `Puppet` I should just describe the resources in classes and I can't do what I want to do.

Could you tell me what I can do?

Comment: I have made extensive changes to your original text in hopes of clarifying your question, however it's still not clear what were the problems that you faced while using puppet classes. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: i was searching a way to administrate ambari server using puppet but i didn't know how to proceed . Right now i'm using curl requests inside Puppet classes , it's working but i don't know if there is a better solution to make puppet communicate with ambari .